# Uploaded file in Django Rest Framework and processing the request for zip

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework, zip

I'm having difficulty knowing how to process the HTTP request from an uploaded file within the Django Rest Framework. The `create` endpoint in my **views.py**:

```
def create(self, request):
    file_iobytes = request.FILES["file"].file
    self.zipping(file_iobytes)

    serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data) # converts to JSON

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


def zipping(self, file):
    # Create a buffer to write the zipfile into
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the zipfile, giving the buffer as the target
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
        #file.seek(0)
        zip_file.write(file)
        file.close()
```

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='Myfiles/')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('timestamp',)
```

My intention is:

1. upload file via DRF
2. create hash from file eg sha1 (which I don't know how to directly because the hashing requires a path, and I don't know how to retrieve this from the http request).
3. zip the file and store it

How can I use the request to create a zip file (is this the right approach)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the comments are self-explanatory :)

```
import hashlib
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


def generate_sha1(file_pointer):
    # BUF_SIZE is totally arbitrary, change for your app!
    BUF_SIZE = 65536  # lets read stuff in 64kb chunks!

    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    while True:
        data = file_pointer.read(BUF_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        sha1.update(data)
    return sha1.hexdigest()


def generate_zip(model_instance):
    source_file = f'{model_instance.file.name}'
    dest_file = f'{source_file}.zip'
    zipfile.ZipFile(dest_file, mode='w').write(source_file)
    return dest_file


def re_assign_files(model_instance, dest_file):
    model_instance.file.delete()  # deletes the uploaded file
    model_instance.file = dest_file  # mapping the generated zip file
    model_instance.save()  # saving the model instance


@api_view(http_method_names=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo_api(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({'message': 'this is get method'})
    else:
        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(True)  # validating the data
        model_instance = serializer.save()  # saving the data into database

        hash_sha1 = generate_sha1(serializer.validated_data['file'])  # generates the SHA1 value
        dest_file = generate_zip(model_instance)  # generates zip file
        re_assign_files(model_instance, dest_file)
        return Response({'sha1': hash_sha1, 'data': serializer.data})
```

Comment: thanks, apart from the generate_zip function all seems ok (there is an issue with where this source is read from, because it doesn't  recognise the directory)

Comment: *".... it doesn't recognise the directory"* I don't understand, could you explain bit more?

Comment: no worries, I had to fiddle around with the directory but it was minor, nothing related to your answer. Thanks again.